# Проверка формы на заполнение java

Tags: java, servlet

Есть сервлет регистрации, в который передаются данные с полей формы. Необходимо реализовать проверку полей на заполненность (Поля не должны быть пустыми)

```
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String name = req.getParameter("name");
    String password = req.getParameter("pass");
    Cat cat = new Cat();
    if (name !=null && password !=null) {
        cat.setEmail(name);
        cat.setPassword(password);
    }
    else {
        resp.setStatus(SC_NO_CONTENT);
    }
    if  (CatService.getInstance().isEx(cat)) {
        resp.setStatus(SC_BAD_REQUEST);
    } else {
        UserService.getInstance().add(cat);
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

    }
```

Что я сделал не так ? и как это можно сделать более красиво ?

Comment: `name !=null` это проверка на null, а что насчет просто пустой строки?

Comment: Ну и в вашем вопросе нет описания проблемы. Что не работает то?

Comment: Захожу на локалхост, специально не заполняю формы и все равно все регистрируется

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String name = req.getParameter("name");
    String password = req.getParameter("pass");
    Cat cat = new Cat();
    if ( name != null && password != null && name.trim().length() != 0 && password.trim().length() != 0 ){
        cat.setEmail(name);
        cat.setPassword(password);
    } else {
        resp.setStatus(SC_NO_CONTENT);
    }
    if ( CatService.getInstance().isEx(cat) ){
        resp.setStatus(SC_BAD_REQUEST);
    } else {
        UserService.getInstance().add(cat);
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

    }
}
```

Comment: Может `StringUtils.isNotBlank(name)`?